# dhcp in Mac Terminal - is this spying?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, server, terminal-server

"dhcp35:~ user$" has appeared in my mac terminal instead of the usual "My-MacBook-Pro:~ user$".

Is this an indication of anything malicious?

I've been messing around [cliclick](https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/cliclick/) to automate key presses from terminal, so not sure if this has resulted from my messing or from something I might have downloaded.

dhcp is documented as part of the [terminal server user guide](ftp://ftp.blackbox.com/manuals/l/LES4xxxA_UG_v3.6.pdf), but I can't work out the significance.

Comment: See this: https://superuser.com/questions/49891/how-can-i-stop-mac-os-x-overriding-my-hostname-when-i-receive-a-dhcp-request-on

Comment: Thanks. So it sounds more like something I'll have accidentally walked into rather than a sign something malicious?

Comment: That would be my guess - I suspect you have connected to a different DHCP server than what you were using previously, and the new DHCP server assigns you a hostname. I'll add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are connected to a DHCP server that sets the hostname along with giving an IP assignment:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-3.14

One way to stop the hostname from changing is to do the following from a Terminal window (assuming you want to name your computer `donald`). You may need to preface these commands with `sudo`:

```
scutil --set ComputerName    donald
scutil --set HostName        donald
scutil --set LocalHostName   donald
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining